# Расширения linq для массивов с количеством элементов большим чем int.MaxValue

Tags: c#, .net

Есть массив, размер которого потенциально может быть `long`. Ну и мне необходимо делать вырезки из этого массива посредством `Skip()` и `Take()`, но они принимают в качестве параметра `int`. Можно, конечно, ручками это запилить перебором, можно даже свои методы расширения для этого сделать, но, может, есть штатные способы?

Comment: Наличие такого массива обычно означает что у вас что-то сильно не так с архитектурой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Нет, таких расширений нет и быть не может по одной простой причине.

Linq работает *не с массивами*. Linq2Objects работает с последовательностями, в которых следующий элемент получить можно только после предыдущего. Поэтому операция наподобие Skip(4000000000) будет выполняться долго - ей же придется перебирать все пропускаемые элементы! Но хуже всего, что она будет выполняться *бессмысленно долго* - ведь тот же самый эффект можно получить намного быстрее если отказаться от абстракции последовательности.

*PS на данный момент из всех рантаймов только Mono поддерживает создание массивов размером больше 2Gb. Вы уверены, что желаете писать настолько непереносимый код?*

Comment: Спасибо за замечание.

Comment: А что будет, если я выполню это var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileName); для очень большого файла? Ведь в NTFS максимальный размер файла 2^64 байт

Comment: @iRumba будет OutOfMemoryException

Comment: @iRumba это и есть причина, по которой большие файлы нельзя читать через ReadAllBytes

Comment: @iRumba если вы задумались над этой проблемой - самое время внимательно изучить такой класс как FileStream

Comment: Еще раз спасибо

Comment: Еще вопрос. Так byte[] это же не последовательность, насколько я знаю и доступ к элементу не требует предыдущего элемента. Или нет? Если так, то почему максимальный размер массива все равно ограничен интом?

Comment: @iRumba потому что Linq работает с последовательностями

Comment: Да забудьте про linq. Я уже про массивы и их размеры

Comment: @iRumba в .NET максимальный размер массива интом не ограничен (см. свойство [LongLength](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.array.longlength(v=vs.110).aspx)). Но менеджер памяти не умеет выделять более 2 гигабайт на один объект, поэтому сверхбольшие массивы невозможны.

Answer (score 2):

Если говорить именно о массивах, то в стандартном CLR для его индекса используется тип `Int32`. Поэтому теоретически массив может содержать не более `Int32.MaxValue` элементов (2,147,483,647). Если массив многомерный, то это ограничение распространяется на каждое его измерение. Но это еще не все. До .NET 4.5 максимальный размер одного объекта (в т.ч. массива) в куче был ограничен 2 Гб, даже для 64-битой платформы. Поэтому попытка создать массив, например, `byte[]` с `Int32.MaxValue` элементов исчерпает лимит памяти для одного объекта.

В .NET 4.5 был добавлен параметр [`gcAllowVeryLargeObjects`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh285054(v=vs.110).aspx), который позволят создавать массивы с максимальным числом элементов, равным `UInt32.MaxValue` (4,294,967,295). Однако, по каждому измерению максимальный допустимый индекс все равно ограничен:

> The maximum index **in any single dimension** is 2,147,483,591 (0x7FFFFFC7) for byte arrays and arrays of single-byte structures, and 2,146,435,071 (0X7FEFFFFF) for other types.

Следовательно, Skip/Take с типом long для массивов смысла не имеет.

Конечно, можно использовать, например, связный список, где число элементов ограничено лишь доступной памятью. Но, как уже было отвечено, это указывает на наличие каких-то проблем в архитектуре приложения.